# Bluetooth thermal printer

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, bluetooth

I try print "teststring" on Bluetooth thermal printer. Manufacturer not have IOS SDK for connect to printer. I used SCPCoreBluetoothManager. I don't know right CBUUID because I do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        CBService *service = [_connectedPeripheral services][indexPath.row];

        NSString* str = @"teststring";
        NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        CBMutableCharacteristic *ch = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[service UUID] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];

        [_connectedPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:ch type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];

        [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [service UUID]]];

        return cell;
    }
```

But printer not print(
manual for printer: yadi.sk/i/gdQQI3DOkX9fR

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your string to a hexadecimal value. Refer to this question, [How do I write <1100> or <2200> to the value of a characteristic on my CBPeripheral?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761171/how-do-i-write-1100-or-2200-to-the-value-of-a-characteristic-on-my-cbperiphe/33762203#33762203).

If that doesn't fix it then you'll have to wait for someone who has experience with this printer to come along or post some more information regarding how to communicate with it.